# globalCompositeOperation on 2 canvases

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have 2 layered canvases, and one has a circle that i would like to see at all times. the circle follows the mouse at all times. the circle is on top, but when the other canvas gets something drawn on it (with similar color), the circle gets really hard to see. I have tried using `globalCompositeOperation`, but it does not work, the circle still disappears.

#### here is some code:

```
    //pos is the mouse position {x:x,y:y}
    ctx2.beginPath()
    ctx2.globalCompositeOperation = "xor";
    ctx1.globalCompositeOperation = "xor";
    ctx2.shadowColor = brush.color
    ctx2.shadowBlur = 1
    ctx2.clearRect(0, 0, brush.prePos.x + brush.size*2, brush.prePos.y + brush.size*2)
    ctx2.arc(pos.x, pos.y, brush.size / 4, 0, Math.PI*2)
    ctx2.stroke()
    ctx2.closePath()
```

Comment: globalCompositeOperation only sets the composite mode for next drawings on the context it has been set. Once the image is produced it doesn't do anything at a presentational level (like would a css property). But to your problem, don't you simply want to place the canvas with the circle at an higher z-index than the other? If this doesn't work, then please clarify more how your two canvases should interop.

Answer (score -1):

Since you have 2 overlapping `canvas` elements you can use the CSS `mix-blend-mode`. I hope this is what you need.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const canvas1 = document.getElementById("canvas1");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const ctx1 = canvas1.getContext("2d");
let cw = canvas.width = canvas1.width = 300,
  cx = cw / 2;
let ch = canvas.height = canvas1.height = 300,
  cy = ch / 2;

let m;
ctx.fillStyle = "red"
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillRect(10,10,200,100);


canvas1.addEventListener("mousemove",(evt)=>{
  m = oMousePos(canvas1, evt);
  ctx1.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  ctx1.beginPath();
  ctx1.arc(m.x,m.y,20,0,2*Math.PI);
  ctx1.fillStyle = "red"
  ctx1.fill();
})



function oMousePos(canvas, evt) {
  var ClientRect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  return { //objeto
    x: Math.round(evt.clientX - ClientRect.left),
    y: Math.round(evt.clientY - ClientRect.top)
  }
}
```

```css
canvas{border:1px solid; position:absolute; top:0;left:0;}
#canvas1{mix-blend-mode: difference;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
```

Comment: Does this work with fillStyle and strokeStyle? when i try applying mix-blend-mode, nothing changes

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out. The style was being overwritten so I fixed it.